# Xorg input devices fail without udev

Tags: linux, xorg, gentoo, udev

#### What I am trying to do:

Launch Xorg server without udev device manager.

#### What I have tried to do:

Make sure that `/dev/` has all required nodes, such as `/dev/input/*`.

Make sure that all required kernel modules are loaded.

Launch `Xorg`.

#### What happens:

`Xorg` starts up as excepted.

`Xorg` loads correct GPU driver and sets right screen resolution.

`Xorg` blocks all input devices (keyboard, mouse), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[1-12]</kbd> does not work (can't go back to `tty1`).

`Unraw`'ing keyboard to take its control from X removes blocking and after `unraw` I can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> back to `tty1`. Xorg still does not handle any input.

#### Why I think that it should work:

Same configuration works well if `udev` is loaded.

Loading `udev` does not add or modify `/dev/` contents, all nodes stays same.

#### My main question is:

How to make Xorg input devices work without `udev`?

Any additional information about how Xorg really uses/detects/grabs keyboard would be helpful. And any additional information about what udev really does (other than populating /dev/) would also be helpful.

Comment: Maybe I should `mv ./my.question /stackexchange/unix/linux/`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't that the device nodes are missing, it's that `X` wants to talk to `udev` to enumerate the input devices.

If you're not going to use `udev` then I suspect you'll have to write a `xorg.conf` that declares the input devices manually.

Comment: Any suggestions about what should I change / look for? Xorg logs reports that keyboard/mice/serverlayout are loaded (layout tree shows up correctly at xorg log). After that comes two lines saying `Automatically adding devices` and `Automatically enabling devices` (both from `==` default settings). Then most interesting line that says `WW Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'umouse' will be disabled.`. And yes, I have `"kbd"` as keyboard driver in xorg.conf. How should it be?

Comment: Still have not found solution for this, however this answer pointed me to right direction. +1 for that.